# LINQ to SQL use query after DataContext Dispose

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Im writing DLL for one project, I just started using LINQ to SQL and after moving all methods to this new dll. I disovered that I can't acess DataContext because it was disposed, I understand why but I'm not sure how I can acess results of query for my main project method so:

My method in DLL

```
 public static IEnumerable<Problem> GetProblemsNewest(int howMuch)
        {
            using (ProblemClassesDataContext context = new ProblemClassesDataContext())
            {
                var problems = (from p in context.Problems orderby p.DateTimeCreated select p).Take(howMuch);

                return problems;
            }
        }
```

Calling it:

```
IEnumerable<Problem> problems = ProblemsManipulation.GetProblemsNewest(10);
//Error can't acess it because it was disposed..
```

This is just first method, I have larger ones so I really need a way to do this. There must be a way to use LINQ to SQL in DLL? I know I can do something Like `.ToList` or `.ToArray` but then I wouldn't be able to acess row properties directly and would have to reference it as problem[0],problem[1] etc. which is even more messy than having tone of code in main project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you are outside of the using statement the context is automatically disposed, so when the IEnumerable is actually enumerated the context is already disposed.

Therefore you need to tell Linq that it should go ahead and actually retrieve the values from the DB while your inside of your `using` statement. You can do so via `ToList()` or `ToArray` (or others).

See the updated code:

```
public static IList<Problem> GetProblemsNewest(int howMuch)
{
    using (ProblemClassesDataContext context = new ProblemClassesDataContext())
    {
        var problems = (from p in context.Problems orderby p.DateTimeCreated select p).Take(howMuch);

        return problems.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should just write method to dispose it in dll and call it after Im done with first method in main project?

Comment: no, the context is not meant to exists for longer period of time, instead use the suggested solution

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
return problems;
```

to this:

```
return problems.ToList();
```

*Explanation*:

The ToList() will iterate through the results and pull them all into memory.  Because this happens inside the using statement, you're fine.  And because it creates a list, your values will be returned.

You could do this in other ways.  The basic idea is to actually retrieve the results before the using statement closes.

An alternate solution would be to avoid the using statement, create an iterator that owns the object and disposes it when the last item has been iterated past.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle it by doing a .ToList() on the IEnumerable before exiting the using block. This will retrieve the records and populate the list. Depending on your scenario this might not be optimal in terms of performance though (you lose the possibility of lazy retrieval and additional filtering of the query)

Answer (score 1):

You have to finish the query inside the using clause, i.e. use ToList() or First() or Count(), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Currently you returning query, and when you want use it, because database connection closed before your usage, you will get an exception, just do:

```
return problems.AsEnumerable()
```

This is because of [deffered execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) manner of linq. In fact your `problems` object is just query, and you should convert it to objects to use it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to use the context in a using; the problem is then you can't use the navigation properties later on, because you'll have the same "object disposed" issue when it tries to load the related data.  What you need to do is let the context live, and return the results directly.  Or, when you return the results, call `ToList()`, and later on query all related data.